# XmlTextReader for XDocument source

Tags: c#, xml

Given an XDocument, how can I obtain an XmlTextReader to its contents?  XDocument.CreateReader() returns a XmlNodeReader, I need an XmlTextReader.

```
var xDoc = new XDocument(...);
var nodeReader = xDoc.CreateReader(); // I need a XmlTextReader
var textReader = new XmlTextReader(????xDoc???);
```

Comment: An existing library only accepts an XmlTextReader, but I used Xml/Linq to build my Xml Document.  I posted a solution below...

Comment: I'd suggest fixing the 'existing library' if at all possible.  `XmlReader` should be the abstraction it accepts - the recommendation has been not to use `XmlTextReader` since .NET 2 was released.

Comment: @CharlesMager: That doesn't surprise me.  As there is an obvious 'difference in behavior' between XmlTextReader and XmlNodeReader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work, not sure why I didn't think of it sooner...

```
var xDoc = new XDocument(...);
var textReader = new XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(xDoc.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is best way, but if you got `XDocument` and cant read xml file to anything else, you could change `XDocument` to `MemoryStream` and create `XmlTextReader' from this stream:

```
        var xmlFile = XDocument.Load(uri);
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        xmlFile.Save(stream);
        stream.Position = 0;
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //do your stuff with file
        }
```